# Template for projects

Tags: project-management-style

Template for projects
I am planning to create a full stack web app (Spring + ReactJS) with my friend to build my portfolio. I've created such apps before, so skills wise I'm good to go. But this time I want to do it in a structured way.

I want to use the "project management" method where I gather requirements, and from that, create a user story, use case diagram, then proceed to code, then test, then deploy (not in order here).

My question is: is there a template for me to follow?

I know "gather requirements" or "user story" or "agile" but I'm unsure on which one to do first. And I am not sure if there are other steps that I need to follow, which is a bit messy. Having a template allows me to do it properly, in order, so I don't miss anything. Something like SDLC.

Most of the tutorials on building apps focus on what the app is about and proceed to code, which is useful. But having the full project management thingy is the ultimate goal, kind of like doing the project for a client. Everything is documented and you show your client diff stages of the project with diff docs as you progress.

Hope my question makes sense.

Comment: There isn't one way to manage your project because that depends on the characteristics of your project. As a result, there isn't a template you can use, unless you already decided on which management approach to use. As your question reads, it seems that your goal is to learn project management, which is a very broad topic. If you have specific questions you might try to ask those instead.

Comment: @Bogdan the issue is i dont know where to start and what to ask. perhaps a generic one? supposed i wanna do a to-do list app using Spring, Mysql and React, what is the common approach? all im asking is a sample or reference so i can slowly start from there

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't boil down the entire PMBOK and the experience of certification into a simple onramp that is going to match your particular needs.  That's kind of the reason the PMBOK is so long; that's why there PM is a profession.  The question is effectively like asking "I'd like to be a (lawyer/doctor/whatever); can you boil brain surgery down into a one page summary for me?

Answer (score 1):

### Try to follow agile software development principles

It is now well established that following [Agile Software Development principles](https://agilemanifesto.org/principles.html) results in more successful outcomes for software development projects. The [Agile Manifesto](https://agilemanifesto.org/) is here. Among the Agile processes, [Scrum](https://www.scrum.org/resources/what-is-scrum) is the dominant software development framework. But, your team is too small to practice Scrum because you will be missing some key roles.

However, you can try to implement the Agile principles in the following ways:

- **Working software over comprehensive documentation**: Put more focus on working software and do only absolutely essential documentation.
- **Deliver working software frequently**: Run two week sprints and deliver fully tested, production ready software every two weeks.
- **Satisfy the customer through early and continuous delivery of valuable software**: Demo the software to the customer at the end of each two weeks and get their feedback.
- **Welcome changing requirements, even late in development**: Based on seeing the demo, if the customer wants to make some changes, accommodate them.
- **Continuous attention to technical excellence**:

1. **Code review**: You have a 2-person team. You can each review the code written by the other.
2. **Write unit tests**: Unit tests help you to refactor code, when needed, without risk of breaking existing functionality.
3. **Write integration tests**: Verify end-to-end functionality is not broken.
4. **Continuous integration**: Run automated tests on each check-in so that issues are not discovered late in the cycle.

- **At regular intervals, the team reflects on how to become more effective, then tunes and adjusts its behavior accordingly**: Every two weeks review your process objectively and make improvements, as needed.

Comment: i have some ida about the stages 1-5 u described, but i think i need guidelines / references in the stages before this eg after gathering requirements, how do i set it in writing? business req -> func reg -> use case -> uml diagrams..  i wanna start code using a proper planning and diagrams. i am tired of coding just like that and ending up missing few key functions and having to refactor the whole code. hope you get where im getting at....

Comment: 1-5 are not stages. These are agile principles. There is no separate 'gathering requirements' stage in agile. You may want to go back and study the why, what and how of agile.

Comment: my question is regarding the steps / stages before this 'principles'. eg,  business req -> func reg -> use case -> uml diagrams. if there a reference or template?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you will require a Project Initiation Document. Even though you are your stakeholder, this is still necessary if you are working on a client's project. This booklet contains a comprehensive overview of your project. It provides a clear picture of the project's scope and deliverables to the project sponsor, team, and key stakeholders. Defines the project budget and outlines what work will be done in the project (i.e. the project plan).

When this document is approved alongside the project's design, in this case, the design for your portfolio website, then you can start the project i.e choose your developers if you haven't already, hold a meeting to tell them about the client requirements and or share the client's pitch deck if required.

After the project has fully started, you now need to keep track of your team’s work schedule as a project manager. These are what you need to track:

What task each team member needs to work on
What days they should work on
How many hours your team has to put in to keep up with the project schedule.

Your project is going to go through phases and you need to constantly track your project progress to ensure that it stays on track. This helps you know what stage your project is at all times.

Also, as a project manager, you must make a status report to regularly update the stakeholders about the project’s progress. This report helps you:

Map your task progress
Make your team aware of issues or change requests in the project
Keep track of all completed and upcoming project milestones.

You always need to keep an eye on your team’s timesheet because timesheets will not only help you monitor your team’s productivity but also help bill your clients or project sponsors accurately. You can keep track of your team’s regular and overtime hours, and a team member’s activity for an entire week, including additional details about their projects, like billable hours.

Because you need a sheet with placeholders to assist you document various project tasks, such as project planning, setting goals, creating work schedules, and managing budgets, I recommend you look at this list to choose which you want: https://www.projectmanager.com/pm-templates

Comment: Thank you! I cant upvote due to my reputation :)

Comment: You can also list out the features required for the project so you can keep track of each iteration and also test them seamlessly. That way when a feature is functional, you can start the next iteration, and if there is a bug while developing this, then it can be fixed during the next iteration. The best thing about agile PM is that customer feedback helps you create value rather than finished products.